# Spring Integration 5.2.2.RELEASE - integration flow convertion with @IntegrationConverter doesn't work with jackson databind

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I upgrade my Spring Boot version from `2.1.8.RELEASE` to `2.2.2.RELEASE` (so Spring Integration from `5.1` to `5.2.2.RELEASE`) and the automatic cast with `@IntegrationConverter` doesn't seem to work anymore if we have a jackson converter inside eligible spring converters.

The converter is automatically declared since I have a dependency to `jackson-databind` declared in my project dependencies. I need for jackson because I have to convert the payload received from HTTP request into java bean. But because this converter is declared, it is used instead of Spring integration `GenericMessageConverter` and it fails to convert because it first try to call `toString()` on the bean and then convert the `toString()` object representation.

I have a sample in host in github : https://github.com/Kruschenstein/spring-integration-playground . This is a simple Spring integration flow where we run a server, that ask an HTTP API depending on user input. The typical application use is running a `telnet localhost 1234` enter a number between `0` and `255`, and a fact about cat will be shown in user terminal.

That is the error log I get when I send a request from the `telnet` client:

```
org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message in bean 'server.transformer#2' for component 'server.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#5'; defined in: 'org.grorg.integration.IntegrationApplication'; from source: 'bean method server'; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'org': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"org.grorg.integration.model.api.Fact@22fae1e0"; line: 1, column: 4]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'org': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"org.grorg.integration.model.api.Fact@22fae1e0"; line: 1, column: 4], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.grorg.integration.model.api.Fact@22fae1e0, headers={errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@cdb23ed, Server=Cowboy, ip_tcp_remotePort=54966, NUM=1, Connection=keep-alive, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, http_statusCode=200 OK, Date=1578329608000, Via=1.1 vegur, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@cdb23ed, Etag=W/"10db9-+ezvkUu4LsJ+zW4+jWiIrVy9v5E", ip_connectionId=localhost:54966:1234:2a75cd25-8e85-4b49-a124-4db58aac3b84, Set-Cookie=connect.sid=s%3A8-aFqwlU8601G1vSPXCnc4Wskla8GzpS.JBIKqFX1%2Fw%2BU7py1QOKqI2G1%2FdJNeUPBxGdGtbXQGIw; Path=/; HttpOnly, id=83b6790f-27f0-6045-3e0e-8b852ca10b46, Content-Length=69049, contentType=application/json;charset=utf-8, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1578329608525}]
```

The first two commit are working method. The first commit works because à force `GenericMessageConverter` to be used. And the second commit just show that it works correctly with Spring integration 5.0.

This is a workaround:

```java
    @Bean(name = IntegrationContextUtils.ARGUMENT_RESOLVER_MESSAGE_CONVERTER_BEAN_NAME)
    public static ConfigurableCompositeMessageConverter configurableCompositeMessageConverter(
            @Qualifier(IntegrationUtils.INTEGRATION_CONVERSION_SERVICE_BEAN_NAME) ConversionService conversionService) {
        return new ConfigurableCompositeMessageConverter(
                Collections.singleton(new GenericMessageConverter(conversionService)));
    }
```

Am I wrongly using type casting with integration flow? Do you have a new solution for casting object with the new version? Or is this just a regression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pulling your sample for playing locally. Stay tuned. Thanks

Comment: Looks like Jackson is complaining because it's being asked to parse the string  `"org.grorg.integration.model.api.Fact@22fae1e0"` as JSON... which it isn't.

Comment: Correct. Looking into that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is indeed with the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` trying to covert a `Fact` instance into a `CatFact`. This one happens just after an `Http.outboundGateway()` - the response comes with a `contentType` header as an `application/json`. And this one is indeed a hint for that `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` to try to convert one object into another.

When I do this in your flow:

```
            .transform(Message.class, m -> {
                Facts facts = (Facts) m.getPayload();
                int num = (int) m.getHeaders().get("NUM");
                return facts.getAll().get(num);
            })
            .headerFilter(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)
            .transform(CatFact.class, id -> id)
```

(pay attention to `headerFilter()`), it comes back to working state with a `GenericMessageConverter`.

This is not a bug or regression. This is just a fact of non-consistent state between headers and payload. We may need to think how to mitigate it though... Feel free to raise a GH issue with some thoughts.